# Merging Words into a Line

Tags: python, text

I am currently using Python v2.6 and trying to merge words into a line. My code supposed to read data from a text file, in which I have two rows of data both of which are strings. Then, it takes the second row data every time, which are the words of sentences, those are separated by delimiter strings, such that:

Inside the .txt:

```
"delimiter_string"
"row_1_data" "row_2_data"  
"row_1_data" "row_2_data"  
"row_1_data" "row_2_data"  
"row_1_data" "row_2_data"  
"row_1_data" "row_2_data"  
"delimiter_string" 
"row_1_data" "row_2_data"  
"row_1_data" "row_2_data"  
...
```

Those "row_2_data" will add-up to a sentence later. Sorry for the long introduction btw.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import re

newLine = ''

for line in sys.stdin:

    word = line.split(' ')[1]

    if word == '<S>+BSTag': 
        continue

    elif word == '</S>+ESTag':
        print newLine
        newLine = ''
        continue

    else:
        w = re.sub('\[.*?]', '', word)

        if newLine == '':
            newLine += w
        else:
            newLine += ' ' + w
```

"BSTag" is the tag for "Sentence Begins" and "ESTag" is for "Sentence Ends": the so called "delimiters". "re.sub" is used for a special purpose and it works as far as I checked.

The problem is that, when I execute this python script from the command line in linux with the following command: $ cat file.txt | script.py | less, I can not see any output, but just a blank file.

For those who are not familiar with linux, I guess the problem has nothing to do with terminal execution, thus you can neglect that part. Simply, the code does not work as intended and I can not find a single mistake.

Any help will be appreciated, and thanks for reading the long post :)

---

Ok, the problem is solved, which was actually a corpus error instead of a coding one. A very odd entry was detected in the text file, which was causing problems. Removing it solved it. You can use both of these approaches: mine and the one presented by "snurre" if you want a similar text processing.

Cheers.

Comment: I would suggest that you try this out in the interpreter, and see what the call to re.sub() is returning and stepping through your code that way (by hand). Or use pdb.set_trace(): http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: I did that already, I wouldn't post a question without checking myself=) re.sub() is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def foo(lines):
    output = []
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        if len(words) < 2:
            word = words[0]
        else:
            word = words[1]
        if word == '</S>+ESTag':
            yield ' '.join(output)
            output = []
        elif word != '<S>+BSTag':
            output.append(words[1])

for sentence in foo(sys.stdin):
    print sentence
```

Your regex is a little funky. From what I can tell, it's replacing anything between (and including) a pair of `[` and `]` with `''`, so it ends up printing empty strings.

Comment: I think it should be `line.split()[-1]`. Otherwise I'd guess the tag lines would throw `IndexError`

Comment: Ah, I think when it hits a tag, `words` will be `["</S>+ESTag"]` so it will hit that `continue` and not the `if`/`elif` below

Comment: sorry, just typing freehand here

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but regex is working like a charm, nothing wrong about it. Yes, you are right, it removes tags of each word that are included in brackets such that, word[tag]. The problem is, why the code of mine prints empty strings?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the script isn't being executed (unless you just excluded the [shebang](http://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#miscellaneous) in the code you posted)

Try this

```
cat file.txt | python script.py | less
```

Comment: Actually I already made the script executable by "chmod +x", and added its path to ".profile" and sourced the profile. What I mean is, "| script.py |" works just fine, otherwise it would give an error.

Comment: @clancularius Ok, was just checking :) the `| less` actually masks any error so I thought it might be the issue

Comment: You are right, less is blind to errors =) It becomes very difficult to track corpus errors, especially when you are dealing with text-processing/NLP